# Issues with adding an Editor via IAM

Tags: google-cloud-iam

I am trying to add a freelancer with a Gmail account and a Google workspace account user.  I start at the project dashboard and click "Add People To This Project" (I have also tried in the IAM tab). I enter the email address in the "New Principals" field, select Editor as Role, then Save. Based on the articles I have read, the user should receive an email to confirm via a link, and the email never arrives (yes, we have checked the spam folder). Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

An email is sent for the role "Owner". For the other roles, no email is sent.

Comment: Thanks! But how do the others get access then? If I set a person to the editor, there is no clear way how they can log in and work on the account.

Comment: @tzujan The users must have an identity with Google accounts, Google Workplace, or Identity Platform. They log in to those platforms first. Google Cloud IAM does not provide authentication.

Comment: Thanks @john-hanley - This is what I thought too, yet there is no obvious link to the the project that they are given access as an editor. I have tested with two separate workspace accounts, where I give editor access to an email address associated with the other Google Workspace, they get no email, and when logging into their own account there is no access to the "editor roll" account.

Comment: @tzujan If the users go to https://console.cloud.google.com/ they will be prompted to log in. If they do not have the editor role after logging in then you made a mistake configuring access. Your original question has been answered. If you have more problems create a new question with details.

Comment: Got to work by switching roles, first form Owner then after they log in the switch to the editor.

Comment: @tzujan - I do not understand the solution in your comment.

Comment: I set up the account as an owner, when the person excepted, I switched them to an editor.

Comment: @tzujan - your method might have worked but is not necessary and poses a security risk.